# Cannot Connect AVR USB ISP 2.0

Tags: usb, avr, isp, detection

After searching for a about 10 hours, this is my last hope.
I've made my own development board, with Atmega8. The program is also ready.
I bought Atmel USB ISP 10pin from a local shop to transfer program, but when I have downloaded burner softwares non of them can recognize usb to transfer the program.
I have connected the pins and the LED lights on the usb ISP and on the board are on.

In device manager the USB (it is divided into two components) is showed under
Human Interface Devices

1. HID-complaint vendor-defined device
2. USB input device.

Errors:

AVRdudess: could not find USB device with vid=0x16c0 pid=0x5dc vendor='www.fischl.de' product='USBasp'

ExtremeBurner: connect USBasp on USB board.

I am using Windows8.1 64bit.

Comment: Contact the supplier for support. Or, buy something like the Atmel-ICE which is supported.

Comment: Its a cheap china made item. I think no need to contact supplier.

Comment: What are the USB vendor and product IDs of the device?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams the are two rows under Hardware IDs

HID\VID_03EB&PID_C8B4&REV_0100 and 
HID\VID_03EB&PID_C8B4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you have stumbled across a [device](http://wiki.efihacks.com/index.php?title=USBasp_Experiences) (note that the pic towards the top of that page is a *legitimate* third-party programmer, the bad programmer is towards the bottom) that no programming software actually has support for.

It can be remedied by flashing with [USBasp](http://www.fischl.de/usbasp/) software modified for the layout of the device, but that of course requires another (working) programmer.

Answer (score 0):

VID_03EB&PID_C8B4 indicates your device is a MX-USBISP. This is *not* a USBASP clone.

It is supported by [Progisp 1.72](http://www.xxl-modellbau.de/abbildungen/quadcopter/flugsteuerung/usbasp/usbasp_hid/progisp172.zip)